# Laptop as a TV Remote

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, remote-control

Is there some way to get the infrared port of my laptop to be used as a remote control for the television? Obviously there is, with limited capability, but what program will do this for free?

WindowsXP compatible would be preferred

Comment: http://www.veg.nildram.co.uk/remote.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinLIRC allows you to transmit and receive standard infrared remote control signals. This allows you to control your computer using almost any standard infrared remote control. It also allows your computer to control other equipment which uses these signals (stereo equipment).

http://winlirc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Please provide some text and a summary of the link. Just a link provides no value to the site.

Comment: I have added the text

Answer (score 0):

In Lan base you can use remote desktop.